# Нужна подсказка по библиотеке maphilight.js

Tags: jquery, map

Использую скрипт maphilight.js (http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) для выделения областей на кастомной карте помещений.
При смене разрешения экрана для пропорционального отображения областей применяю вот такой код:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.map').maphilight({strokeColor: '424d5c'});
});
```

Картинка карты уменьшается согласно css. Области тоже должны уменьшаться. На декстопе работает, на айпаде нет.
Кто использует эту библиотеку, подскажите, куда копать? Пока что придумал обновлять страницу, при обновлении все четко, при обычной смене портрет-ландшафт - **нет**.

**UPD.**
По просьбе коллеги дополню вопрос - при смене ориентации на айпаде событие resize срабатывает (проверено через смену цвета блока), т.е. ** на АЙПАДЕ не реинициализируется функция maphilight**. При этом на декстопе при смене размера окна функция maphilight реинициализируется!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, у вас не задан `viewport` мета-тег, из-за чего ширина `$(window)` не меняется при повороте экрана айпада. В `<head>` блоке должна быть такая строка:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: та нэ!!)) ну что вы, смеетесь? тогда бы наверное все было бы кривое...

Comment: Отнюдь, ничего кривого бы не было, а вот скрипт при смене ориентации как раз бы и не срабатывал ;)

Comment: Давайте попробуем локализовать проблему, и я улучшу ответ. У вас не срабатывает либо событие 'resize', либо реинициализация maphilight на айпаде. Вставьте в скрипт перед инициализацией maphilight что-нибудь, меняющее заметную область на странице. Например, изменение цвета блока на рандомный. И проверьте на айпаде, меняется цвет или нет. Если не меняется - значит проблема в несрабатывании события `resize`. И будем идти в эту сторону.

Comment: не срабатывает реинициализация maphilight на айпаде. причем также пробовал вместо $(window).on('resize', function() { функцию window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() { - точно также - цвет блока меняется, maphilight - нет

Comment: Картинка как бы остается шире чем экран, причем в обоих направлениях - с узкого портрета на широкий ландшафт и обратно - всегда картинка получается чуть шире